# Flash library for eyes tracking

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, webcam

I found a solution [example](http://blog.inspirit.ru/?p=416), but it does not help to determine the movement of pupils of the eyes. Do not tell me whether there is a flash library to register the movements of the eyes (pupils) with the help of webcams?

Comment: I don't understand your second sentence, do you DO or NOT want to know about libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I happen to have had a few AS3 classes in school with motion tracking, that makes use of your webcam. I have no clue of how to use it but I still have the source code of the AS3 code we used.
Here you can find the two packages:

- [MotionTracker.zip](http://www.tjardokrijt.nl/MotionTracker.zip)
- [MotionTracking.zip](http://www.tjardokrijt.nl/MotionTracking.zip)

They're coded by a guy named Grant Skinner and I do not know what the copyright and restricions on them are, so be warned :)

Here you can find more, and perhaps updated versions:
  http://www.insurgent.com.ar/en/tag/grant-skinner-en/

I hope this will help!